# Iterate through column to check for value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, string-comparison

I am trying to iterate through a column of a csv file and to check for each iteration if the value can be found in another csv file.
Better would be to check if two values of two columns within the same row can be found in another csv file.

for example:

```
CSV1 with column 1-10
```

and

```
CSV2 with column 1-10
```

Now I am looking for certain strings which are in column1 and column2 of CSV1
and see if I can find them in CSV2.

lets say in CSV1 we have this

```
      Column 1       Column2
row1: "Hello"        "you"
row2: "How are you"  "me"
row3: "xyz"          "youme"
row4: "xyz"          "meyou"
...
row10:"xyz"          "xyz"
```

and CSV2

```
      Column1        Column2
row1: "Hello"        "no"
row2: "How are you"  "me"
row3: "Hello"        "you"
row4: "xyz"          "yes"
...
row10:"xyz"          "xyz"
```

And I want to iterate through the rows of CSV1, take the value of `column1` and `column2` of `row1` and see if I can find them in `CSV2` (they can be in any column in `CSV2` but both will be in the same row)

If for example the first combination of `CSV1` `column1` and `column2` of `row1` can be found in any `row` of `CSV2`
I want to have a `True` to indicate me which row does exist and which doesnt.

In my example I want to take "Hello" and "you" of `CSV1` `row1` and want to check if this combination does occur anywhere in `CSV2` but only if both "Hello" AND "you" exist. Otherwise print out `false`.

So it would print out the following result for `CSV2`

```
row1: false
row2: false
row3: true
....
```

So far I used `isin` so check if a value exists and then compared them manually in excel, which is not very useful. It would be better to build up a loop around it, but I am not quite sure how.

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: your sample data does not represent what you are trying to do - it only has one column.  provide something representative.  You also have not defined your matching logic - do you want to find rows in *CSV2* where *col1* **and** *col2* match a row in *CSV1* , alternatively where *col1* **or** *col2* match?

Answer (score 0):

There's simpler solutions without iterating if you use `Numpy` arrays and functionality.

Comments explain the approach

```py
col1 = ["hello","world","to start"]
col2 = ["technology", "python", "pandas", "fullstack"]

# generate some data sets that can have same values in col1 and col2
csv1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[col1[random.randint(0, len(col1)-1)], col2[random.randint(0, len(col2)-1)]] 
     for i in range(5)], columns=["col1","col2"])
csv2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[col1[random.randint(0, len(col1)-1)], col2[random.randint(0, len(col2)-1)]] 
     for i in range(20)], columns=["col1","col2"])

# get an array of the unique combinations of col1 and col2 in CSV1
myfind = np.array(csv1.groupby(["col1","col2"])
                  .agg({"col1":"first","col2":"first"}).reset_index(drop=True))

# use numpy isin to add a column to CSV2 if it's found in CSV1
csv2m = csv2.assign(
    # where CSV1 col1 + col2 == CSV2 col1+col2
    found=np.isin(csv2.loc[:,["col1","col2"]].sum(axis=1), myfind.sum(axis=1) ),
    # where CSV2 col1 in CSV1 col1 and CSV2 col2 in CSV1 col2
    partialfound=np.isin(csv2.loc[:,["col1","col2"]], myfind ).all(axis=1))

print(f"CSV1\n{csv1.to_string(index=False)}\n\nCSV2 with matches\n{csv2m.to_string(index=False)}")
```

**output**

```
CSV1
     col1        col2
 to start  technology
 to start  technology
    world      pandas
    hello  technology
 to start      pandas

CSV2 with matches
     col1        col2  found  partialfound
    world      python  False         False
 to start  technology   True          True
    hello      python  False         False
 to start      pandas   True          True
    world      python  False         False
    hello      pandas  False          True
    hello   fullstack  False         False
    world      pandas   True          True
 to start      python  False         False
    hello      python  False         False
 to start  technology   True          True
    world  technology  False          True
    world   fullstack  False         False
 to start      python  False         False
    hello   fullstack  False         False
    world      pandas   True          True
    world   fullstack  False         False
    hello   fullstack  False         False
    world   fullstack  False         False
    hello  technology   True          True
```